# Excel copy paste

Tags: excel, copy, paste

I have Excel sheets where we have values in cells A3 to R3. Some of the cells contain formulas in it - name, date, count, time etc. We will enter values in other cells and the answer will be pulled up into A3 to R3 according to formulas mentioned above.

The values alone need to be pasted in sheet 2 in rows one by one datewise on a daily basis if sheet 1 has different date in one click.

Example:

```
Jay 26.07.2016 15 7.45 18 7.45 sheet 1 values on 26th
Jay 27.07.2016 23 8.45 35 8.32 sheet 1 on 27th
```

The same has to be copied to sheet2 like

```
Jay 26.07.2016 15 7.45 18 7.45
Jay 27.07.2016 23 8.45 35 8.32
```

Can anyone help me on this...

Comment: reformatted the same

Comment: Improved language..

Comment: @Sounder Got anything on this?